# Modelling transition times parametrically in multi-state models (in R)

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I've been trying to understand multi-state modelling (MSM) for my use case, which is a simple illness-death model. For a standard 2-state survival analysis I often use parametric models of the time-to-event, as it is easier to extrapolate my model to predict pathways for new individuals. I'm a fan of the `flexsurv` R package for this purpose.

However, the bulk of the R packages for MSM seem to involve non or semi-parametric methods, such as `mstate` which uses the standard Cox formulation for modelling the transition hazards. Another popular package, `msm`, uses Hidden Markov Models.

I'm curious as to why modelling the transition times with standard parametric families such as the Weibull isn't commonly used (as far as I can tell).

For example, in my illness death model I could fit three separate Weibull models to the three different transitions, rather than using the `coxph` function from the `survival` package as described by Putter http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2712/full

Would modelling these transitions parametrically be correct, or am I breaking any fundamental assumption? If so, how would I then obtain the transition probabilities

$P_{ij}(s, t) = Pr(X(t) = i | X(s) = j)$

From what I've read, the common way of obtaining these is using the non-parametric Aalen-Johansen estimator from the baseline hazards of a Cox model of the transition hazards.

Comment: I hoped you had an extensive reply here..